# Authenticate imaplib.IMAP4_SSL against an Exchange imap server with AUTH=NTLM

Tags: python, exchange-server, imap, ntlm

Yesterday, the IT department made changes to the Exchange server. I was previously able to use `imaplib` to fetch messages from the server. But now it seems they have turned off the authentication mechanism I was using. From the output below, it looks as if the server now supports NTLM authentication only.

```
>>> from imaplib import IMAP4_SSL
>>> s = IMAP4_SSL("my.imap.server")
>>> s.capabilities
('IMAP4', 'IMAP4REV1', 'IDLE', 'LOGIN-REFERRALS', 'MAILBOX-REFERRALS', 
'NAMESPACE', 'LITERAL+', 'UIDPLUS', 'CHILDREN', 'AUTH=NTLM')
>>> s.login("username", "password")
...
imaplib.error: Clear text passwords have been disabled for this protocol.
```

Questions:

1. How do I authenticate to the imap server using NTLM with imaplib? I assume I have need to use IMAP4_SSL.authenticate("NTLM", authobject) to do this? How do I set up the authobject callback.
2. Since SSL/TLS is the only way to connect to the server, re-enabling clear text password authentication should not be a security risk. Correct?

The process that connects to the imap server is running on Linux, BTW. So I am not able to use pywin32.

**Edit:**

I was able to figure out 1. myself. But how about 2.: Clear text passwords in IMAP over SSL is not a security problem, is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to use the [python-ntlm](http://code.google.com/p/python-ntlm/) project.

`python-ntlm` implements NTLM authentication for HTTP. It was easy to add NTLM authentication for IMAP by extending this project.

I submitted [a patch for the project](http://code.google.com/p/python-ntlm/issues/detail?id=15) with my additions.